# Rails 3 and Formtastic. How to display fields according to selection (ajax)?

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, formtastic

If I have shipments, each shipment has one of four possible modes. When I want to create an invoice, I go to New Invoice, select shipment from select menu (what shipment the invoice is for). If the shipment selected has mode A, then some fields will be displayed in the form; If the shipment selected has mode B, then some other fields will be displayed.

All I need is that in the New Invoice form, when someone selected a shipment, to ajaxily find the shipment's mode (shipment.mode).

Comment: Instead of ajax you can add this contents while building form and hide or show according fields to the shipment mode selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this in a way similar to this:

### Your view:

```
<div data-shipment-mode="A" style="display:none;">
    fields that should only be shown for shipment mode A
</div>
<div data-shipment-mode="B" style="display:none;">
    fields that should only be shown for shipment mode B
</div>
```

### Your JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('id-of-shipment-select-menu').change(function() {
        var successHandler = function(data) {
            var mode = data.mode;
            $("div[data-shipment-mode!=" + mode + "]").hide();
            $("div[data-shipment-mode=" + mode + "]").show();
        };

        var shipmentId = $(this).val();
        /* replace service_url with the appropriate controller/action */
        $.getJSON("/service_url/" + shipmentId, successHandler);
    });
});
```

Initially all mode-dependent fields are hidden. Then when you select a shipment, the `change` callback will be invoked. It sends a request to a service (controller action) that returns the mode for the given shipment. And you use this mode and only show those divs that their `data-shipment-mode` has the same value.

You can even expand this, and when you hide a div, you can clear the values of all the inputs (and selects, etc.) within it as well as disabling them.

You can avoid sending the request to the server, if you embed the mode for each shipment in its option tag:

### View:

```
<option id="A_SHIPMENT_ID" 
        data-shipment-mode="SHIPMENT_MODE_FOR_THIS_SHIPMENT">
        Shipment A
</option>
```

### JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('id-of-shipment-select-menu').change(function(e) {
        var mode = $(e.target).data("shipment-mode");
        $("div[data-shipment-mode!=" + mode + "]").hide();
        $("div[data-shipment-mode=" + mode + "]").show();
    });
});
```